# Alternative to using asp:Timer for client updates

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, client-server

I have an asp.net web application that uses a timer to update all clients with new data. The data isn't in a database but is in a public static object shared by all clients. The timer has an OnTick method that updates each client's controls with this global data so all clients can view the most recent data. I'd like to update data fairly quickly, so I have the timer's interval set to 1 second.

The issue I've been seeing since implementing this timer is that sometimes button presses don't do anything. Sometimes (at random) the user has to click the button twice or more for anything to happen while other times a click works the first time. My guess is the button presses that have no effect happen because they were pressed at the same time the timer was executing the OnTick method (please correct me if I'm wrong). I set the timer interval to a much longer period and I didn't see these ineffectual button presses, so I know it has something to do with interference from the timer.

Is there an alternative to using timers and OnTick to update all client controls (without requiring each client to initiate or request the update)? Is there an event-driven way to update all clients rather than relying on a timer (i.e. all clients update on change in global data/on calling a certain method in the server code rather than at a set interval)?